# Why my pandas library (along with some other lib) does not work on my jupyter when it does work in my PyCharm

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

I am a very beginner to programming, and I recently faced this problem that I did not even know how to begin solving.

I have installed pandas and scikit library (through pip install) on my anaconda, and have been successfully using these libraries in my PyCharm.

But when I turned to my jupyter notebook and tried importing these libraries, it responded that it is not installed. (my jupyter and PyCharm are connected to the same anaconda)

I am very curious to why this problem arises and how I could solve this.

Comment: Pretty hard to do any analysis from here. What is the output of: 
`conda env list`,
`which conda` and
`which python` ?

Comment: # conda environments:
#
tensorflow               C:\Users\pc\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow
root                  *  C:\Users\pc\Anaconda3

Comment: this is the result of conda env list...

Comment: Seems like you've got two environments installed: `tensorflow` and the default `root`. Try the following things: First do `pip freeze | grep pandas`.  I assume it will not show you any result. Then do this: `source activate tensorflow` and then `pip freeze | grep pandas`. Can you report back with results?

Comment: Could you provide the output of:
`import sys;    print(sys.path)` for us?

Comment: @MichaelGecht 
It shows "pandas==0.20.1"

Comment: ['C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2\\helpers\\pydev', 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2\\helpers\\pydev', 'C:\\Users\\pc\\Anaconda3\\python36.zip', 'C:\\Users\\pc\\Anaconda3\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\pc\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\pc\\Anaconda3', 'C:\\Users\\pc\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\pc\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Sphinx-1.5.6-py3.6.egg',

Comment: 'C:\\Users\\pc\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\pc\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\pc\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\Users\\pc\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions', 'C:\\Users\\pc\\PycharmProjects\\Jupyter', 'C:/Users/pc/PycharmProjects/Jupyter']

Comment: above two are my pycharm

Comment: and this is my jupyter

['', 'C:\\Users\\pc\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow\\python35.zip', 'C:\\Users\\pc\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\pc\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\pc\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow', 'C:\\Users\\pc\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\pc\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.5.egg', 'C:\\Users\\pc\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions', 'C:\\Users\\pc\\.ipython']